# Multiple background image with repeat

Tags: css

I'm trying to set multiple background images on my body.

In order to do so, I made this which works, but isn't really doing what I want.

```
body { background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/100/100'),url('https://picsum.photos/100/100'),url('https://picsum.photos/100/100'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat; 
background-position: center,right top,left top;
background-size: 80%,110px,110px;}
```

As you will see, there are three images, one to the center, and two others on the sides.

In fact I would like to have the center image with the property `repeat` in order to really cover the entire body. But If I do that, the two others backgrounds seems to be hidden by the center one. I would like to have the two others backgrounds coming in front of the first center background.

I want also the sides background to be sticky, but this is the next step.

Comment: the one you want to cover the full area with need to be the bottom one, so the last one in the list not the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
body { 
margin: 0;
background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/100/100'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center,right top,left top;
background-size: 100%;
}

body:before{
content: "";
background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/100/100);
background-size: cover;
width: 200px;
height: 100vh;
float: left;
}

body:after{
content: "";
background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/100/100);
background-size: cover;
width: 200px;
height: 100vh;
float: right;
}
```